# Share Folder on same LAN, yet different domains

Tags: network-shares, windows-server-2012

Okay guys, got a strange one. 
On a single switch, same VLAN, I have a server (Windows Server 2012) and a client (Windows 10). Due to my organization's terrible IT management, the client is on a domain from a separate site and the server is on a local work group. I am trying to access an SMB file share (hosted on the server) fron the client desktop. My issue is that I'm not able to authenticate on to the share drive when I attempt to map it.

I have local admin on the server, but not the client (go figure) and I am not a domain admin. The client's domain controller is also unreachable from this LAN (site specific, locked by a firewall).

How do I set my server to accept credentials from a domain that it isn't a member of and can't even touch the DC? If this is impossible, is there a way to map a share drive using local credentials on the server machine given that the client is a member of a domain?

Answer (score 0):

One of the ideas behind an active directory domain controller is to centralized authorization (The user authenticate up against the DC).
If now a stand alone server can do the same using the same credentials and SID from another domain then the idea is broken.
But what I think you could do is simple to map the network drive using a user account from the server.
So first a user login on the Windows 10, next he maps the network drive using some of the servers user credentials. Your Windows 10 will probably try to map the drive with the domain user account, but I think there is an option to select other credentials.